# Confused about PhantomJS localStorage behavior

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

The first tiem I run this it prints "before: null; after: zxcv" as I expect.  The *second* time I run it, it prints the same thing -- why is setting localStorage not persisting to the next run?  (PhantomJS 1.9.8 on Windows.)

```
webPage = require ('webpage');
page = webPage.create();
page.open('http://localhost:8080/mysite/', function(status) {
  var foo;

  foo = page.evaluate(function() {
    return localStorage['asdf'];
  });

 console.log("before: " + foo);

  foo = page.evaluate(function() {
    localStorage['asdf'] = 'zxcv';
    return localStorage['asdf'];
  });

  console.log("after: " + foo);

  phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Behaves the same way with PhantomJS 2.0.1-dev on Windows and Raspbian. Regardless of access (array notation vs. getItem/setItem)

Comment: Just realised that you're the OP on the other question too...!

Comment: #smh  agree it's a dup  -- unfortunately my fix from last time is not working